# Why different names for ngClass and NgClass

Tags: angularjs

`NgClass` is a Directive and it is exported as `ngClass`. What is the advantage of a different name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular normalises the attributes on an element to camel case when it tries to find the matching directive, so you need to export the directive name as camel case too or it won't match. See the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) under 'Normalization'.

> **AngularJS normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine
> which elements match which directives**. We typically refer to
> directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g.
> ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to
> directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using
> dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).
>
> The normalization process is as follows:
>
> 1. Strip x- and data- from the front of the element/attributes.
> 2. Convert
>    the :, -, or _-delimited name to camelCase.

Comment: Yeah, the normalization can be confusing at first since it's entirely automated on all directives.